# Get full html (including textarea content) from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div 'someDiv'. In that div I have a table, and in the table's cells, I have textareas.

I want that when a certain button is clicked 'mybutton', the full html (it might has changed because the user put some data in the cells), will be put inside a hidden field.

All of that - using Jquery.

Of course, I tried `$('#someDiv').html()` but it gives me the original html and not what the user put.

EDIT: here is the code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RCQmj/

```
<div id="interviewSummarySkeleton">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea class="title" tabindex="1">title 1:</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="content" tabindex="8"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea class="title" tabindex="2">title 2:</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="content" tabindex="9"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="interviewHtmlHere">PUT HERE THE HTML FROM PREV DIV AFTER USER CHANGED IT</div>
```

Comment: ok, this is classic so what have you tried?

Comment: we're not here to make code for you, the propose of this forum is to help when you struggle.

Comment: You wanted to write `$('#somDiv').html()`, right? It looks strange when the only piece of code you gave us is incorrect.

Comment: I had just put a link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the innerHTML of each textarea to the value before your `html()` call:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZuXwQ/1/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('body').find("textarea").each( function() {
        this.innerHTML = this.value;
    }); 
    console.log($('body').html());
});
```

Here it is applied to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RCQmj/1/
Here again, if you want it added as text: http://jsfiddle.net/RCQmj/2/

in either case, I'm assuming `interviewHtmlHere` is hidden in your actual context?

Comment: [Adapted to the situation](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuXwQ/1/) with `#someDiv` and a table containing the textarea just for the sake of it. Good job on that answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the button - you will have to set all the textarea's text to it's value before getting the .html()

```
$('button').click(function(){ 
    $('#interviewSummarySkeleton textarea').text(function(){
       return this.value; 
    });    
    $('#interviewHtmlHere').text($('#interviewSummarySkeleton').html());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hy3bW/)

Answer (score 1):

The [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method will get the full HTML-code of any element, using jQuery.

Comment: I don't think `.html()` will get the user input values of a `textarea`. http://jsfiddle.net/ZuXwQ/ - Oh and I didn't downvote you

Comment: I downvoted you, you should not just say, use this and that's it ... if you want to proper answer the question, do it, but never as you did. See the difference between your type of answer and the other 2. Answers such as "use this or that"  should be a comment!